# Is there a simple way to run an authenticated Google Analytics query using curl?

Tags: curl, google-analytics, google-api

I’d like to run a Google Analytics API query using curl, on the command line, and I am puzzled by the available authentication methods. I hoped I would simply get a client ID and a secret to pass along with the curl request, but all the OAuth authentication stuff looks like it insists on a round-trip through a server or a browser.

What’s the easiest way to “persistently”, once and for all until revoked, authenticate a command-line script to query Google Analytics, then? I don’t want to open a browser each time I want to run the script.

Comment: Are you asking about doing this using *just* curl, or are you more broadly asking about doing this from the command line (possibly with more than one round trip) without having to go through the browser-based username/password flow each time? If you're asking about doing this with *just* curl, the answer is that it's impossible.

Comment: Not being able to use just a single curl call sucks, but I can understand that. How would the more complex command-line solution look, can you add that as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: This might help with your research https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices?hl=en it's still going to be a lot of back and forth, once setup its relatively easy with say a PHP script but with straight CURL you're going to run into a lot of back and forth with tokens.

Comment: It’s not really the back-and-forth that bugs me as much as the user interaction. Just tried a Haskell library and that also prompts me to open an URL in a browser and copy some token back in order to authenticate. That’s pretty ugly for a shell script.

Comment: Unfortunately the first time you connect to any service through OAuth you're going to be required to visit a URL, however a good implementation of any of Google's API's should only require this to happen once, you'll then receive a refresh token which can be used for subsequent requests (and you can have your cron jobs work without human interaction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have arrived at, so far:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Yaml
import Control.Monad
import Data.ByteString.Char8 (pack, unpack)
import Data.Monoid
import Network.Google.OAuth2
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import Network.HTTP.Types (hAuthorization)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B8
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L8

data OAuth2Credentials = OAuth2Credentials {
    getClientID :: String,
    getClientSecret :: String
} deriving (Show, Eq)

instance FromJSON OAuth2Credentials where
    parseJSON (Object value) = OAuth2Credentials <$>
        value .:  "clientID" <*>
        value .:  "clientSecret"
    parseJSON _ = mzero

parseOAuth2Credentials :: String -> Maybe OAuth2Credentials
parseOAuth2Credentials source = Data.Yaml.decode $ pack source

main :: IO ()
main = do
    source <- readFile "analytics-credentials.yml"
    let creds = parseOAuth2Credentials source
    case creds of
        Just creds -> do
            let client = OAuth2Client (getClientID creds) (getClientSecret creds)
            token <- getAccessToken client authScope (Just tokenCacheFile)
            request <- parseUrl analyticsQueryURL
            response <- withManager $ httpLbs $ authorize token request
            L8.putStrLn $ responseBody response
        Nothing -> return ()
    where
        authorize token request = request { requestHeaders = [(hAuthorization, B8.pack $ "Bearer " <> token)] }
        analyticsQueryURL = "…"
        authScope = ["https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/"]
        tokenCacheFile = "analytics-token.yml"
```

Not exactly curl and not exactly simple, but after the initial browser-based token generation the access tokens are cached in a file and subsequent requests don’t need any human interaction.